# How to make catched promises fail in jest

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

Consider this function:

```
aPromise = require('axios');    
function middleware(callback) {
  axios.get('/api/get')
    .then(callback)
    .catch(callback);
}
```

Consider this test:

```
const callback = (err) => {
  expect(isError(err)).toBe(true);
  done();
};

middleware(callback);
```

*The `isError` is a lodash function.*

Consider `aPromise` as something I want to test. If the promise always resolves, this test should not pass. But it will! And that's because the promise's catch actually catches the `expect` exception.

My question is: How to not catch the error in a promise's `catch` handler when `expect` throws an error in the promise's `then` handler?

Note that I don't use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a failed promise and you need to return the promise in your test. Please have a look on the [doc on testing promises](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content).

```
aPromise = require('axios');    
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  get: ()=> jest.fn() //initialy mock the get function
})

it('catch failing promises',() = > {
    const result  = Promise.reject('someError'); //create a rejected promises
    aPromise.get.mockImplementation(() => result)// let `get` return the rejected promise
    const callback = jest.fn()
    middleware(callback)

    return result
        .then (()=>{
          expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('someError');
        })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought it is not important; But I don't have access to the promise in my test. I should test a function with callback. The implementation uses a promise. I have changed the question.

Comment: Then you either need to  return  the promise from your function  or you need to mock the creation of the promise.

Comment: I cannot return promise but I can mock the promise. Can you modify your answer?

Comment: Then you need to modify the question first ;), so I can see how do you get `aPromise` into your module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127543/discussion-between-alisabzevari-and-andreas-koberle).