# How can I use promises to catch errors when they might not be wrapped in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

### Background

I am using Promises, and I have a multitude of functions that may or may not return a Promise and that may or may not fail, like in the example below:

```
//does not return a Promise, simply a string
let goodFun = function(){
    return "I like bananas!";
};

//blows up!
let badFun = function(){
    throw "A general error blaahh!"; 
};

//You get the point ...
```

Since these functions may or may not return Promises and may or may not fail, I need to wait for all of them to execute. To achieve this I have a function to call them all and wait for their execution:

```
let asyncFun = function(){
    return Promise.all([badFun(), goodFun()]);
};
```

### Problem

So far so good. My code calls `asyncFun` and I expect some of its functions to actually fail. To be prepared, I added a catch:

```
let executor = function(){

    let numbsArray = [1, 2, 3];
    let respArray = [];

    for(let num of numbsArray){
        respArray.push(
            asyncFun()
                .catch( error => console.log(`I failed with ${error} and ${num}`))
        );
    }

    return Promise.all(respArray);
};
```

The problem is that `catch` is not catching anything at all!

Even adding a catch to the function calling the `executor` is not catching anything !

```
executor()
    .catch(error => console.log("Failed miserably to catch error!"));
```

### Research

I don't really understand why my catch clauses are not catching the exception. To find out, I read this discussion:

- [How to make catched promises fail in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402024/how-to-make-catched-promises-fail-in-jest)

Which leads me to believe that all my functions `goodFun` and `badFun`, no matter what, must always return a promise.

This is confusing for me, because according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) the array may contain a Promise, or a result from one (like a string, or a number).

I would also like to avoid adding even *more* boiler plate code to my functions ....

### Question:

1. How do I fix my code, so the catches work adding a minimum or boilerplate code?

### Code

```js
let goodFun = function() {
  return "I like bananas!";
};

let badFun = function() {
  throw "A general error blaahh!";
};



let asyncFun = function() {
  return Promise.all([badFun(), goodFun()]);
};

let executor = function() {

  let numbsArray = [1, 2, 3];
  let respArray = [];

  for (let num of numbsArray) {
    respArray.push(
      asyncFun()
      .catch(error => console.log(`I failed with ${error} and ${num}`))
    );
  }

  return Promise.all(respArray);
};

executor()
  .catch(error => console.log("Failed miserably to catch error!"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `.catch`es are not working is that the errors are being thrown *synchronously*. The code execution never even executes that .catch() instruction to set up a catch handler because the error has already been thrown and the code execution has gone elsewhere. If you wrapped everything in an ordinary `try-catch`, I think you'd see it catching the errors you're throwing.

Example:

```js
let goodFun = function() {
  return "I like bananas!";
};

//blows up!
let badFun = function() {
  throw "A general error blaahh!";
};

try {
  Promise.all([goodFun(), badFun()])
    .then(results => console.log(results))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Wups, I caught an error. This wasn't supposed to happen.", e);
}
```

> This is confusing for me, because according to the MDN documentation the array may contain a Promise, or a result from one (like a string, or a number).

The MDN documentation is absolutely correct, but if `badFun()` throws an error, there's nothing that `Promise.all` can do about it, because the the program flow will be going down the call stack looking for something to catch the error that was thrown.

If you're not sure whether some code is synchronous or promise-based (or if it will throw a synchronous error), you can use this to safely wrap it a promise:

```
function executeSafe(action) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(action);
}
```

This will shield action() from any "boom" that takes place.

Example:

```js
let executeSafe = 
  action => Promise.resolve().then(action);

let goodFun = 
  () => "I like bananas!";

//blows up!
let badFun = 
  () => { throw "A general error blaahh!" };

Promise.all([goodFun, badFun].map(executeSafe))
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

FYI, if you're using Bluebird, then it has a built-in method `Promise.try`, that serves the same purpose as `executeSafe` above: `Promise.all([goodFun, badFun].map(Promise.try))`.

Here's your full example with the needed modifications:

```js
let executeSafe =
  action => Promise.resolve().then(action);

let goodFun =
  () => "I like bananas!";

//blows up!
let badFun =
  () => {
    throw "A general error blaahh!"
  };

let asyncFun =
  () => Promise.all([goodFun, badFun].map(executeSafe));

let executor = function() {
  let numbsArray = [1, 2, 3];

  return Promise.all(numbsArray.map(num =>
    asyncFun()
    .catch(error => console.log(`I failed with ${error} and ${num}`))
  ));
}

executor();
```

And here it is with the `.catch` outside of the `executor`:

```js
let executeSafe =
  action => Promise.resolve().then(action);

let goodFun =
  () => "I like bananas!";

//blows up!
let badFun =
  () => {
    throw "A general error blaahh!"
  };

let asyncFun =
  () => Promise.all([goodFun, badFun].map(executeSafe));

let executor = function() {
  let numbsArray = [1, 2, 3];

  return Promise.all(numbsArray.map(asyncFun));
}

executor().catch(error => console.error("Miserably failed to catch anything.", error));
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to do something along the lines of `function executeSafe(action) { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ try { return resolve(action()); } catch(e) { reject(e); }`?

Comment: @GGG No, that would be very superfluous. The logic inside `.then()` is designed to catch errors and turn them into rejected promises.

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't knew that behavior inside of `.then()`

Comment: @GGG Yep. Also bear in mind that `new Promise()` also turns errors into rejected promises, so putting a try-catch inside it like that would serve no purpose.

Comment: Thank you! I'll re-read the docs to update myself on Promises

Comment: After reading your answer, I modified `asyncFun` to be 

`let asyncFun = ()  => Promise.all([badFun(), goodFun()].map(executeSafe));`

 However I am still having the same issue. According to you, my `Promise.all` **should** have a catch statement, right ? My main objective would be to let the error go and only catch it in the `executor` function. Would that be possible ?

Comment: Even changing `let asyncFun = () => Promise.all([badFun(), goodFun()].map(executeSafe))
    .catch(console.log);` won't fix it ... I am kinda lost :S

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix The problem is that you still have `()` after `badFun` and `goodFun`. Remove those and it should work. `let asyncFun = () => Promise.all([badFun, goodFun].map(executeSafe))` Just hit the Run Code Snippet button in my answer to see that it works. _"According to you, my Promise.all should have a catch statement, right ?"_ No, I'm not telling you where to put a catch statement. You should be able to catch it after `executor()` if you remove the `catch`es inside it and remove those parentheses.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Added a few more examples for you.

Comment: Got it! Thanks !

Comment: Hello, if you feel like getting some more points, consider having a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839462/promise-then-and-catch-clauses-not-working