# Promise then and catch clauses not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

## Background

I have a multitude of functions that may or may not return a Promise and that may or may not fail, like in the examples below:

```
let goodFun = (fruit) => `I like ${fruit}`;

let badFun = (fruit) => {
    throw `${fruit} is spoiled!`;
};

let badPromise = (fruit) => new Promise( (fulfil, reject) => {
    reject(`Promise failed with ${fruit}`);
});

let goodPromise = (fruit) => new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
    fulfil(`Promise succeeded with ${fruit}`);
});
```

Because each function may or may not return a promise, which may or may not fail, I modified `executeSafe` from [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808381/how-can-i-use-promises-to-catch-errors-when-they-might-not-be-wrapped-in-a-promi), that takes a function and its arguments as parameters, and then *Promisifies* the function and its result:

```
let executeSafe =
    (fun, ...args) => Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        return fun(...args);
    });
```

My objective with all of this, is to have an `asyncFun` function that waits for the execution of a batch of functions that were Promisified and then returns whatever came from executing them:

```
let asyncFun = 
(fruit) => 
    Promise.all([badFun, goodFun, badPromise, goodPromise].map(
        fun => executeSafe(fun, fruit)
    )
);
```

## Problem

`asyncFun` is designed to run the multitude of functions previously described and some of them I actually expect to see fail. To accommodate for this my `asyncFun` function has a `catch` clause. This clause only works with `badFun` and doesn't work with `badPromise`. The `then` clause never works.

```
let executor = () => {
    let fruitsArr = ["banana", "orange", "apple"];
    let results = [];

    for (let fruit of fruitsArr)
        results.push(
            asyncFun(fruit)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
            })
        );

    return Promise.all(results);
};
```

Not even placing the `catch` clause in the executor's call catches anything else other than the `badFun` errors.

```
executor()
    .catch(error => console.log("Failed miserably to catch error!"));
```

## Code

```js
let goodFun = (fruit) => {
  return `I like ${fruit}`;
};

let badFun = (fruit) => {
  throw `${fruit} is spoiled!`;
};

let badPromise = (fruit) => Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  throw `Promise failed with ${fruit}`;
});

let goodPromise = (fruit) => Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  return `Promise succeded with ${fruit}`;
});

let executeSafe =
  (fun, ...args) => Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return fun(...args);
  });

let asyncFun = (fruit) => Promise.all([badFun, goodFun, badPromise, goodPromise].map(fun => executeSafe(fun, fruit)));

let executor = () => {
  let fruitsArr = ["banana", "orange", "apple"];
  let results = [];

  for (let fruit of fruitsArr)
    results.push(
      asyncFun(fruit)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
      })
    );

  return Promise.all(results);
};

executor()
  .catch(error => console.log("Failed miserably to catch error!"));
```

Question:

- How to fix my code so that its `then` and `catch` clauses in `asyncFun` work as intended?

Comment: This is really confusing, and I would argue not at all how its done. Why are you calling `Promise.resolve().then` instead of using the promise constructor? You're `catch`ing in the inner async calls but not re-throwing, how is the outer `catch` going to do anything?

Comment: As for `Promise.resolve` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: The executor catch would ideally not catch anything because the `asynFun` catch would do all the work. However, none of them are working.

Comment: I know how/why it works, but its unusual meaning anyone used to working with Promises will have a hard time reading your code.

Comment: I am open to suggestions, if you think there is a better way to Promisify functions, I am all ears !

Comment: Updated code to be more *familiar* to promise lovers!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Your update actually uses an antipractice. If you want to create a rejected promise from a non-promise value, you can just use ``Promise.reject(`Promise failed with ${fruit}`)``.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Similarly, to create a successful promise from a non-promise value, just use ``Promise.resolve(`Promise succeeded with ${fruit}`)``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are misunderstanding how `Promise.all()` works. The way it works is that if *all* of the promises succeed, it resolves to an array of values. If *any* of them fail, it rejects with the *first error that occurred*.

What you seem to be expecting, that the successful ones are caught in the `then` and the failed ones are caught in the `catch`, is not possible. A promise either resolves once or it rejects once. It doesn't do both, and it won't do one or the other multiple times. `Promise.all()` returns a single promise so it will either resolve or reject.

Third party promise libraries do have methods for "settling" an array of promises - basically waiting until they have all done their thing (succeeded or failed), and resolving to an array of the results. You can implement it like this:

```js
// values is an array of promises and/or non-promise values
function allSettled(values) {
  let settle =
    value => Promise.resolve(value)
    .then(result => ({ state: "fulfilled", value: result }))
    .catch(error => ({ state: "rejected", reason: error }));

  return Promise.all(values.map(settle));
}

// example usage
allSettled(['hello', 'goodbye', Promise.resolve('good'), Promise.reject('bad')])
  .then(results => console.log(results));
```

Then you can use it like below.

On an unrelated note, I've also modified your approach so that you don't need the modified version of `executeSave` that takes `...args` (I think that's a convoluted way to go about it). You can create functions that use the arguments *before* you pass them into `_executeSafe_`:

```js
let goodFun = (fruit) => `I like ${fruit}`;

let badFun = (fruit) => {
  throw `${fruit} is spoiled!`;
};

let badPromise = (fruit) => Promise.reject(`Promise failed with ${fruit}`);

let goodPromise = (fruit) => Promise.resolve(`Promise succeeded with ${fruit}`);

let executeSafe = fun => Promise.resolve().then(fun);

function allSettled(values) {
  let settle = 
    value => Promise.resolve(value)
      .then(result => ({ state: "fulfilled", value: result }))
      .catch(error => ({ state: "rejected", reason: error }));

  return Promise.all(values.map(settle));
}

let asyncFun =
  (fruit) =>
    allSettled([badFun, goodFun, badPromise, goodPromise]
      .map(fun => () => fun(fruit))
      .map(executeSafe)
    );

asyncFun("orange").then(results => console.log(results));
```

Additional side note - if you wanted to use the `promisify` function from Jared Smith's answer, then you could change your `asyncFun` function to this:

```
let asyncFun =
  (fruit) =>
    allSettled([badFun, goodFun, badPromise, goodPromise]
      .map(promisify)
      .map(fun => fun(fruit))
    );
```

Comment: Such a rockie mistake from my part, I can't believe it ...  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So this works, catches fine. If the function passed to `promisify` returns a promise, it just gets passed up the chain.

```
var fnThatThrows = s => { throw new Error(s) };
var identity = x => x;

var promisify = f => (...args) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  try {
    res(f(...args));
  } catch (e) {
    rej(e);
  }
});

var rejected = promisify(fnThatThrows);
rejected("foo").then(_ => console.log("shouldn't see")).catch(e => console.log(e)); // logs error

var succeded = promisify(identity);
succeeded("foo").then(val => console.log(val)); // logs 'foo'
```

If the promise from the argument function is rejected, that gets passed along too:

```
var returnsBadPromise = s => Promise.reject(new Error(s));
promisify(returnsBadPromise)("foo").catch(e => console.log(e)); // logs error
```

Comment: The `catch` there is redundant. A thrown error in the `Promise` constructor will be converted to a rejected promise. So this would suffice: `var promisify = f => (...args) => new Promise(res => res(f(...args)));`.